# Basic increment in C

Tags: c

I have a very basic doubt, I tried the following code in C.

```
i=(++i)+(++i)+(++i);
```

I expected the answer to be 6 but the answer came out to be 7. How is it this possible ?increment in C

Comment: What was the initial value of i?

Comment: It doesn't matter what i is. It's UB.

Comment: `i=0` would make sense, i.e. what OP is expecting - 1+2+3 = 6.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, so post an answer explaining why it's UB.

Comment: It does if you're expecting the answer to be 6! I would presume `i=0` since that would naively produce `i = 1 + 2 + 3`

Comment: Irrespective of the answer, you should avoid such expressions. Its a bad programming practice. Code should be readable and not obfuscated. Most of such questions come up during interviews (I consider them bad interview questions!).

Comment: @zaphod What if the interviewer wants a response "Yuck! Don't ever do that even in Java or C# where it's defined behaviour!"?

Comment: Yup, thats the right way to answer that question. "Yuck, I would never code in that manner!" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Assigning multiple times to a single memory location between two sequence points yields undefined behaviour, no certain value or behaviour is to be expected.

Rule of thumb: Do not assign multiple times to a single value within a single expression:

```
++i; ++i; i+= i; // okay
++i + ++i;       // not okay
```

Comment: Assigning multiple times to a single memory location *in a single sequence point*. `i = i + 1; i = i + 1;` is fine ;).

Comment: @Zeta, that makes much more sense.